# Compare the digits of two integers in each decimal position

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure I am describing the problem using the correct terms, my math English is not that good.

What I need to do is check if they match for each digit of two integers based on the position of the digit: ones, tens, .. etc

For example check the following table of different numbers and the wanted comparison result:

```
number1 | number2 | desired result
-----------------------------------
100     | 101     | 001
443     | 143     | 300
7001    | 8000    | 1001
6001    | 8000    | 2001
19      | 09      | 10
```

Basically I need the absolute value of subtraction for each digit alone. So for the first example:

```
1 0 0
1 0 1 -
--------
0 0 1
```

And second:

```
4 4 3
1 4 3 -
-------
3 0 0
```

And third:

```
7 0 0 1
8 0 0 0 -
---------
1 0 0 1
```

This needs to be done in mysql. Any ideas please?

Comment: You're right, thanks! Just corrected it.

Comment: is there any limit in the number of digits of number1 and number2? Will both numbers to compare always same length?

Comment: No worries about it, I can always pad it.

Comment: what's the max number of digits ?

Comment: It could reach to 10 digits

Comment: Since this will require an iterative operation, I feel maybe writing a stored procedure is what would be needed.

Comment: so, for each digit you need the abs difference: (3-1 = 2 and also 1-3=2) correct?

Comment: @verhie You are right.

Comment: would you expect to compare values with different length, like 1000 and 100. Then you need to lpad both strings to equal length first: 1000 and 0100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job if your numbers are below 10000.
If they exceed, simply modify the query ;)

```
    SELECT number1,
           number2,
           REVERSE(CONCAT(ABS(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number1), 1, 1) - SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number2), 1, 1)),
           IF(CHAR_LENGTH(number1) > 1, ABS(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number1), 2, 1) - SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number2), 2, 1)), ''),
           IF(CHAR_LENGTH(number1) > 2, ABS(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number1), 3, 1) - SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number2), 3, 1)), ''), 
           IF(CHAR_LENGTH(number1) > 3, ABS(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number1), 4, 1) - SUBSTRING(REVERSE(number2), 4, 1)), ''))) as `desired result`
    FROM numbers
```

for 3 digit numbers:

```
SELECT number1,
       number2,
       CONCAT(
           ABS(SUBSTRING(number1, 1, 1) - SUBSTRING(number2, 1,1)), 
           ABS(SUBSTRING(number1, 2, 1) - SUBSTRING(number2, 2,1)),
           ABS(SUBSTRING(number1, 3, 1) - SUBSTRING(number2, 3,1))
       )
FROM numbers
```

actually you don't have reverse the string at all. this comes from a more mathematical approach I tried before ;)

Comment: 8000 - 7001 != 1001, which is apparently the desired result for line 3.

Comment: Please check the examples above, I don't need simply (number1 - number2)

Comment: Nice, but shouldn't it put '0' in the ELSE instead of '' ?

Comment: The output is a string. if you put the '0' in the else part of the length check you'd end up with:
`100 - 101 = 0001` instead if `001`

Comment: Woha! that's great! even when I don't fully understand what's going on here. Now the question, if I had a fixed number length, should I use one if statement?

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it for a while, I guess I do understand it and already got the answer to my silly question. Thanks man! I'm already adding another related question in a different thread.

Comment: If you have a fixed number length you can make it quite a bit simpler because you don't have to reverse an so on....
let me adjust the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it with integers only, it can be done this way (for 5 digits as an example):

```
select abs(number1/10000 - number2/10000) * 10000 +
       abs(number1/1000 % 10 - number2/100 % 10) * 1000 +
       abs(number1/100 % 10 - number2/100 % 10) * 100 +
       abs(number1/10 % 10 - number2/10 % 10) * 10 +
       abs(number1 % 10 - number2 % 10)
```